# Is it safe to use a bash script to create a daemon?

Tags: bash

I would like to create an entirely automated box (based on something like a Raspberry-Pi or OLinuXino card).

My box would run a Debian based system with a read-only filesystem and a ramdisk (to avoid SD card corruptions).

I would like to create a script that automatically connects to a remote server (via ssh) each time the box is switched on or plugged to a network.

To do so, I think my simplest solution is to create a shell script running as a daemon. This daemon will have to stay alive until the box is shut down or disconnected from network. The script should be able to reconnect when network is up or box restarts.

The question: do you think a shell script is safe enough to perform this ? Or should I better use another (and safer) programming language (PERL, C, ...) ?

Answer (score 7):

Many Daemons are run using bash as the scripting language. You won't have any issues using it.

Comment: any daemons in particular...?

Comment: I want to be sure: I want the daemon program to be written using bash, not only to be ran from a bash script.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, it is quite tricky to create a daemon in bash (or shell-script in general). Some problems like background fork, output and error messages redirection or signal handling are not easy to get right.

For the specific problem you describe there is already some (free) software doing automatic ssh connexion with respawn.

I use [`autossh`](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/) for this purpose. It is packaged in Debian and works great.

Comment: fyi background forks in bash are as easy as encasing the command in parentheses. Output and error messages are equally as easy using bash. I guess it all depends how well you know the scripting language. As far as using autossh instead, I second that motion!

Comment: I have seen bash rather effectively used as server monitoring and firewall daemon, its not that useless...

Answer (score 1):

It is quite safe, but it can be less than useful unless `bash` is in a position to handle the cleanup. If it is killed for any reason, the script needs to be capable of `exec`ing itself in order to refresh its state as necessary - you probably don't want to simply do:

```
while :
```

...for instance. That gets old pretty fast. Instead maybe do something like:

```
trap '' HUP EXIT
set_state() { echo stuff="'$(otherstuff)'"... ; }
chk_interval() { wait for something... ; }
exec_me() { exec env - $(set_state) "$0" <in >out 2>alsoout & ; }
chk_interval
exec_me
```

It can also depend on who is doing the cleanup. The *simplest* means of implementing a daemon is like:

```
init=path/to/executable/script
```

...on the kernel commandline for particularly single-purposed installations. Where the relative `/` inferred here is the initramfs `/`.